# Where should I ask a question about the use of the Google Maps API?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm looking for which site I should go to to ask questions about the Google API, in this case specifically the Google Map API. I want to ask a questions  about the use of the API. Stack Overflow is the closest, but my questions are not strictly programming questions, but questions about the API itself.

Where should I ask my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Maps API is highly on-topic for focused Q&A at the [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com).

Click below for examples of questions that have been asked there for:

- [Google Maps API generally](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api)
- [Google Maps API 3.0 specifically](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3)